# No syntax error but not printing result

Tags: c++

I can't get the sum to print out
I did not get any warnings or such.

Trying to do this question here:http://projecteuler.net/problem=1 
the program runs and then just stalls forever.

```
// Adding multiples of this and following equations
#include "std_lib_cmpt125.h"

void SumMultiple(int Max,int Base)
{
    int i=0;
    int sum=0;
    for(i;i<Max;i+Base)
        {
            sum=i+sum;
        };
    cout<<"The sum"<<sum;
}
int main()
{
    int base=0;
    int max=0;
    int sum=0;
    cout<<"Please enter the sum's multiple: (ex. 3: 3,6,9,12...)\n";
    cin>>base;
    cout<<"Please enter the sum's maximum: (ex. 10000)\n";
    cin>>max;
    SumMultiple(max,base);
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: No need of debugger here .. a good practice although 
you can clearly see what the mistake was as given in my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed to increment the *i*,

```
for(i;i<Max;i=i+Base)
{
..
}
```

Or

```
for(i;i<Max;i+=Base)
 {
  ..
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I overlooked that ><

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
int i=0;
int sum=0;
for(i;i<Max;i+Base)
{
   sum=i+sum;
};
```

To:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Max; i += Base)
{
  sum += i;
}
```

Note that the first statement in the original `for` loop does nothing, that the value of `i` must be incremented (which is accomplished most simply with the `+=` operator), and that the semicolon after the closing brace is unnecessary.

It's customary in C++ to declare a loop variable in the loop itself, to limit its scope and emphasize its purpose as a counter.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra Brace } at the end and you are not incrementing i

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
for(i;i<Max;i+Base)
        {
            sum=i+sum;
        };
    cout<<"The sum"<<sum;
```

into

```
for(i;i<Max;i=i+Base)
        {
            sum=i+sum;
        };
    cout<<"The sum"<<sum;
```

or

```
for(i;i<Max;i+=Base)
        {
            sum=i+sum;
        };
    cout<<"The sum"<<sum;
```

The above code will increment the counter i and display the necessary result

Answer (score 0):

Also you aren't going to get the answer with that function. problem 1 is looking for the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 from [1..999]

try this

```
for ( int i = 1; i < Max ; i++ ) 
    sum += ((i % 3 && i % 5) ? 0 : i ; 
return sum
```